# PYTHON 'result' is not defined File "<string>", line 64, in <module> File "<string>", line 40, in cont

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def calculate():
    operation = input('''
Please type in the math operation you would like to complete:
+ for addition
- for subtraction
* for multiplication
/ for division
''')

    number_1 = int(input('Please enter the first number: '))
    number_2 = int(input('Please enter the second number: '))

    if operation == '+':
        result = number_1 + number_2
        print(number_1, "+", number_2, "=", result)

    elif operation == '-':
        result = number_1 - number_2
        print(number_1, "-", number_2, "=", result)
    elif operation == '*':
        result = number_1 * number_2
        print(number_1, "*", number_2, "=", result)
      
    elif operation == '/':
        result = number_1 / number_2
        print(number_1, "/", number_2, "=", result)
       

    else:
        print('You have not typed a valid operator, please run the program again.')
        return result


def cont():
    calc_again = input("Do you want to continue?")

    if calc_again.upper() == 'Y':
       Tempresult = result
       
       cntr = 0
       while cntr == 0:
           num3 = int(input("Enter next number: "))
           operation = input('''
Please type in the math operation you would like to complete:
+ for addition
- for subtraction
* for multiplication
/ for division
''')
           if operation == '+':
             result1 = Tempresult + num3
             print(result1)
           else:
             print('hi')
           
    else: 
        print('See you later.')
    


calculate()
cont()
```

Comment: File "<string>", line 62, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 38, in cont
NameError: name 'result' is not defined

Comment: Please explain what you want this code to do, what the problem is, and what you have tried in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Please update title & add supportive description like what is expected and what happened. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to follow SO standards & also to get quick & better help from StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is throwing error because `result` is local variable of `calculate()` . In order to access it in `cont()` , you have to make it `global` .

```
def calculate():
    #global variable
    global result
    operation = input('''
Please type in the math operation you would like to complete:
+ for addition
- for subtraction
* for multiplication
/ for division
''')

    number_1 = int(input('Please enter the first number: '))
    number_2 = int(input('Please enter the second number: '))

    if operation == '+':
        result = number_1 + number_2
        print(number_1, "+", number_2, "=", result)

    elif operation == '-':
        result = number_1 - number_2
        print(number_1, "-", number_2, "=", result)
    elif operation == '*':
        result = number_1 * number_2
        print(number_1, "*", number_2, "=", result)
      
    elif operation == '/':
        result = number_1 / number_2
        print(number_1, "/", number_2, "=", result)
       

    else:
        print('You have not typed a valid operator, please run the program again.')
        return result


def cont():
    global result
    calc_again = input("Do you want to continue?")

    if calc_again.upper() == 'Y':
       Tempresult = result
       
       cntr = 0
       while cntr == 0:
           num3 = int(input("Enter next number: "))
           operation = input('''
Please type in the math operation you would like to complete:
+ for addition
- for subtraction
* for multiplication
/ for division
''')
           if operation == '+':
             result1 = Tempresult + num3
             print(result1)
           else:
             print('hi')
           
    else: 
        print('See you later.')
    

#variable declaration
result=None
calculate()
cont()
```

Comment: thankyouu!!! it helps a lot!!! but can i ask if how can you continue use the result and ask if want to add again to the result?

Comment: can you explain the problem clearly ? For example , Do you want to continue addition operation many times . Or should calculator not stop until user exit out of it?

Comment: continuing to add a number to the first result and asking if still want to add or want to exit

Answer (score 0):

The `result` variable is local. Define the `result` variable globally. And, use `global result` inside the function implementation, to instruct the function not to create a new variable result, rather update the global variable.

Here is a hint.

```py
result = 0 # default value

def function(n1, n2, operation):
    global result

    if operation == '+':
        result = n1 + n2
        return result
    else:
        return 0
```

Digressing a bit from the question, give a thought about the following code (python3+):

```py
def function(n1, n2, operation):
    if operation == '+':
        print(f'{n1} + {n2} = {n1+n2}')
        return n1 + n2
    else:
        return 0
```